# How to display X axis coordinates when touching an element (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display the X axis coordinates of the screen by touching an element.

The code works if I remove

```
getElementById("name")
```

But then it runs when I touch any were on the screen, rendering all other buttons or touch elements useless. I want it to work if I touch an element. But nothing happens when I run the code as it is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<script>

  var x;

  document.getElementById("name").addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    x = e.touches[0].pageX;
    alert(x);
  });

</script>

<div id="name" style="background-color:black; width:100%;height:700px;">hi</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated and if I am using addEventListener() incorrectly please let me know as it is the first time I am using it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<script>` block is on the page before your HTML elements, and the code is trying to attach an event listener to an element that has not been read yet. Move your `<script>` block to the bottom of the `<body>` and your code will run.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you so much. Stupid mistake from my side but I am *NOT* going to be making it again.

Comment: As a best practice I would use external JavaScript, putting your `<script>` tags in your `<head>`, then use a load Event, so the DOM Elements exist before you get them.

Comment: Yeah I'll start doing that from now on. Thanx again